# Calculation of no. of packets sent received and dropped from a trace file in NS2.34

Tags: ns2

How to distinguish and count the sent, dropped and received packets from trace file in ns2.34? I only need the data packets(sent, received and dropped) not control packets like ACK.
Please if there any tool to trace the .tr file then it is good for me.
    I am attaching my trace file.

Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 1):

Use Below awk script,

```
BEGIN {

        sendLine = 0;

        recvLine = 0;

        fowardLine = 0;

}



$0 ~/^s.* AGT/ {

        sendLine ++ ;

}



$0 ~/^r.* AGT/ {

        recvLine ++ ;

}



$0 ~/^f.* RTR/ {

        fowardLine ++ ;

}


$0 ~/^D.* cbr/ {

        dropLine ++ ;

}

END {
printf "Packet Sent: %d\n,sendLine"
printf "Packet Received: %d\n,recvLine"
printf "Packet Drop: %d\n,dropLine"


        printf "PacketDelivery Ratio:%.4f \n",(recvLine/sendLine);
}
```